# Can not see mystore catalog on WCMS/catalog (hybris)

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I created b2b store. I changed mystoreinitialdata/impex store names to my store name.

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# [y] hybris Platform
#
# Copyright (c) 2018 SAP SE or an SAP affiliate company.  All rights reserved.
#
# This software is the confidential and proprietary information of SAP
# ("Confidential Information"). You shall not disclose such Confidential
# Information and shall use it only in accordance with the terms of the
# license agreement you entered into with SAP.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# ImpEx for Points of Service

# Macros / Replacement Parameter definitions
$storeUid=mystore
$productCatalog=mystoreProductCatalog

$catalogVersion=catalogversion(catalog(id[default=$productCatalog]),version[default='Staged'])[unique=true,default=$productCatalog:Staged]
$storeImage=storeImage(qualifier, $catalogVersion)

INSERT_UPDATE OpeningSchedule;code[unique=true];

INSERT_UPDATE WeekdayOpeningDay;openingSchedule(code)[unique=true];dayOfWeek(code)[unique=true];openingTime[dateformat=hh:mm];closingTime[dateformat=hh:mm];

INSERT_UPDATE SpecialOpeningDay;openingSchedule(code)[unique=true];date[unique=true,dateformat=dd.MM.yyyy];closed;openingTime[dateformat=hh:mm];closingTime[dateformat=hh:mm]

INSERT_UPDATE Address;&addrID;streetname;streetnumber;postalcode[unique=true];town[unique=true];country(isocode);region(isocode);phone1;owner(PointOfService.name)[unique=true]

INSERT_UPDATE StoreLocatorFeature;code[unique=true]

INSERT_UPDATE PointOfService;name[unique=true];type(code);address(&addrID);latitude;longitude;geocodeTimestamp[dateformat=dd-MM-yyyy];$storeImage;openingSchedule(code);basestore(uid)[default=$storeUid];features(code)

UPDATE PointOfService;name[unique=true];features(code);

INSERT_UPDATE PoS2WarehouseRel;source(name)[unique=true];target(code)[unique=true]
```

impexes like that.

Then i made ant initialize and when i go to `backoffice/catalog/catalogs`

i dont see my store. (which is `mystore`)

i see default ones apparel, powertools etc just like before.

What should i do, java side things?

this is content catalog/catalogimpex

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
# [y] hybris Platform
#
# Copyright (c) 2018 SAP SE or an SAP affiliate company.  All rights reserved.
#
# This software is the confidential and proprietary information of SAP
# ("Confidential Information"). You shall not disclose such Confidential
# Information and shall use it only in accordance with the terms of the
# license agreement you entered into with SAP.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# Import the Content Catalog
#
$contentCatalog=mystoreContentCatalog
$languages=ja,en,de,zh

# Content catalog for CMS contents
INSERT_UPDATE ContentCatalog;id[unique=true]
;$contentCatalog

# Catalog versions for content catalogs
INSERT_UPDATE CatalogVersion;catalog(id)[unique=true];version[unique=true];active;languages(isoCode)
;$contentCatalog;Staged;false;$languages
;$contentCatalog;Online;true;$languages
```

Answer (score 0):

The impex you sent actually does not change a single item. Impex uses a header where you define the operation (INSERT, INSERT_UPDATE, UPDATE, REMOVE), what data type you want to change and the attributes you want to change. In the next lines there need to be one or more lines of csv data.

Consider this example:

```
UPDATE PointOfService;name[unique=true];features(code);
;myPointOfService;feature1,feature2;
```

This impex script changes the point of service identified by its name (myPointOfService) and sets the attribute features to the two features identified by the feature codes feature1 and feature2. First line is the header and second line is the data. Since your script only contains headers, there will be no change.

If you want to create a catalog consider changing the following files:

```
/mystoreinitialdata/resources/mystoreinitialdata/import/coredata/contentCatalogs/catalogName/catalog.impex
/mystoreinitialdata/resources/mystoreinitialdata/import/coredata/productCatalogs/catalogName/catalog.impex
```

Comment: i changed `$contentCatalog` and `$classificationCatalog` to mystore already but it did not create

Comment: Have a look at this java class: de.hybris.mystore.initialdata.setup.InitialDataSystemSetup especially the method createProjectData(...). The comment tells you exactly how to write the method, so your data is imported. The names you add there need to match the folder names in /mystoreinitialdata/resources/mystoreinitialdata/import/coredata/contentCatalogs/ and /mystoreinitialdata/resources/mystoreinitialdata/import/coredata/productCatalogs/ and /mystoreinitialdata/resources/mystoreinitialdata/import/coredata/stores/ as well as their sampledata counterparts.

Comment: yes they are matching. no error. each name was changed just like here https://wiki.hybris.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=294094418 but i did not add that part `INSERT_UPDATE BaseStore2DeliveryModeRel;source(uid)[unique=true];target(code)[unique=true]
;hybris;premium-net` it has `INSERT_UPDATE BaseStore2DeliveryModeRel;source(uid)[unique=true];target(code)[unique=true]`